# Missing Indices in Elasticsearch after 6.30pm UTC

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a ingestion pipeline that will create indices every 2 hours, eg: index-2022-05-10-**0** at 12am UTC, index-2022-05-10-**1** at 2am UTC and so on..The problem is after 7pm UTC there is no index seen in Elasticsearch. Is it due to the timezone issue? But I know Elasticsearch uses UTC and ES servers are also configured on UTC.

What might be the issue? The new index for next day is created at UTC 12am correctly. And if I see the index creation time according to IST, its 5.30am.

Since I am working from India, and its 5.30 hours ahead of UTC so when its 7pm utc, then in IST the day changes and its 12.30am, is that the time zone issue due to which further indices are not created? Could someone please help?

Below is the pipeline code
...

"script": { "lang": "painless", "source": "Date d=new Date((long)(timestampfield)*1000); DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("HH"); String crh=(Integer.parseInt(f.format(d))/2).toString(); String nvFormat="yyyy-MM-dd-"+crh; DateFormat f2=new SimpleDateFormat(nvFormat); ctx['_index']="index-"+f2.format(d);"

---

Comment: Have you looked into (index lifecycle management) ILM ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html this can acheive the same thing without the using a custom script.

Comment: why are you creating new indices every 2 hours?

Comment: Actually this is already implemented and now the issue needs to be resolved, can I add some script on failure? And indices are created every 2 hours to manage longer retention and shards